# Cannot start debugging: Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:29308

Tags: android, xamarin, virtual-machine, adb, hyper-v

I'm developing a Xamarin Form app in Visual Studio installed in a VM created with Hyper-V. With ADB and port forwarding (https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home) I connect my physical device to VM in wi-fi mode.

Visual studio in VM see correctly the device but when i start debugging, the app is installed correctly in my device but debug crashes when app is going to open. The output of Visual Studio is:

Cannot start debugging: Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:29308: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:29309
Couldn't connect debugger. You can see more details in Xamarin Diagnostic output and the full exception on logs.

On Xamarin Diagnostic output can't see anything that can make me understand what the problem could be.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Do you have developer mode enabled in the app? And do you allow apps to be installed from unidentified sources?

Comment: @Saamer yes. In fact the app is correctly installed in the smartphone but debug doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update SDK Platform Tools at latest.